# Declarative language support in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, declarative-programming

I am developing a simulation engine with Visual Studio that will offer support for building business process simulations. One of the key features will be a declarative language that will allow business users to setup quickly a simulation model. I will give a very brief example of what I mean:

```
initialise simulation.

create 100 resources.

create 50 jobs.

create 2 teams of resources.

start simulation with 10 runs.
```

So I would like something similar to the above in Visual Studio to define the simulation models. Now I know how to do this with other environments like java and groovy but I need to develop it in VS as this is what my company uses. Any ideas as to what I can find in VS?

Cheers.

Comment: This question doesn't really make sense. VS is not a programming language, and thus you can't really do any sort of simulation with "VS". Please clarify what language you want, then we can help you out.

Comment: I think your answer does not make sense. VS is a development environment which can host a number of languages. Is there support for a declarative one? I am developing the simulation engine as it says above. Read carefully please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mention Groovy, I would think that either [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/) or [IronRuby](http://ironruby.codeplex.com/) would fit the bill. Ruby is supposed to be well suited to DSL (domain specific language) programming.

Answer (score 0):

[Windows Workflow Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663328) (WF) is not exactly a simulator or simulation language but the framework supports declarative programming and robust software development (which may be customized to perform the type of simulations).

Visual Studio 2010 (VS2010) comes with WF that enables users to create software programs or long-running processes as a sequence of tasks (or workflow). A WF workflow can be expressed declaratively in an XML markup language called XAML or with a visual designer tool, or procedurally through a .NET-supported language like C# or VB.NET. All the above approaches are supported in VS2010.

WF provides a robust runtime that support the disparate blocks of activities in a workflow to run asynchronously. In addition, the current WF also has support for messaging through web service or WCF services and data integration with data sources through ADO.NET and other .NET data frameworks. A message- or data-driven application can be integrated into a WF workflow.

Comment: I have seen windows workflow foundation but I was looking for something like Groovy to be honest. Once again I am developing the simulation engine so I dont need the declarative part for that. What I would like is to instantiate the whole simulation by using a declarative language.